# How to generate fan power in Chroma Squad?

Tags: chroma-squad

In Chroma Squad, when you hire a marketing agency, you can activate several bonuses that cost "fan power". After an episode is recorded, you collect some amount of fan power, which you can use to activate more buffs, if you have enough. What determines this amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, aside the Income Conversion Rate there also is a Fan Conversion Rate which works the same. Both are based on your total viewership.

For Example: if you have 10.000 Viewers and a Fan Conversion Rate of 5%, you receive 500 Fans (10.000 * 0.05).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked... unless you are implying that gained fan power is equal to new fans per episode.

Comment: @Mauricio yes, those are the fans you gain per episode. Fan Power, in this context, is like man power, so it translates to how many fans you have.

Comment: We're still talking about bonuses from marketing agencies, right? If so, I'll accept your answer

Comment: @Mauricio A marketing agency doesn't really give you fans, it just can increase your conversion rate. But yes, the viewership*conversion rate is the amount you can spend on Agencies.